# correct implementation of the method messageReceived () (Netty)

Tags: java, server, netty

How to fix this writing methods `messageReceived()`.
More precisely how to configure the server's response depending on the content of the message connected client.

```
String fromClientData ="";
String [] params;
User user;
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws IOException {
    fromClientData = e.getMessage().toString();
    params = fromClientData.split(";");
    String idOrDemo = params[1];

    if (params[0].equals("demo")) {
        user = useService.getById(idOrDemo);
        e.getChannel().write("demo;" + user.getId() + ";");
    }

    if (params[0].equals("site")) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(idOrDemo);
        user = userService2.getById(id);

        if (params[2].split(":")[0].equals("SOME")) {
            //todo something
        }

        ctx.getChannel().write("SOME:" + str + ";");    
    } else {

        user.setChannelUser(e.getChannel());
        if (params[1].equals("updateCache")) {
            sendUpdate();
        }
        else {
            setClient();
        }
    }
    } else {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(idOrDemo);
        user = userService.getById(id);

        user.setChannelUser(e.getChannel());
        if (params[1].equals("updateCache")) {
            sendUpdate();
        }
        else {
            setClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more info about you need? and provide an example of you frame structure?

Answer (score 0):

First, after

```
e.getChannel().write("demo;" + user.getId() + ";");
```

you need do:

`e.getChannel().flush()` or replace to `e.getChannel().writeAndFlush("demo;" + user.getId() + ";");`

Second, after split, I recommend change the conditional in the if to:

```
if ("demo".equals(params[0])) { }
```

because, if `params[0]` is null you will have a NullPointerException.